# Adodb Active Record vs Zend db_table

Tags: php, zend-framework, activerecord, adodb, zend-db-table

I use Adodb and Active Record for database abstraction.  I have started to use Zend Framework, and one of the reasons I like it so much is due to it's "Use at Will" architecture which allows me to continue using Adodb rather than Zend's db_table functionality.

I have taken a look at Zend_DB_Table on paper, but really want to know from someone that has experience in them both, what the differences are and if one is better?  Is it worth switching to db_table?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know Adodb , but one of the nice Features about `Zend_Db_Table` is that it is used system-wide. You can set an DefaultAdapter in your Bootstrap an all Objects extending `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` are able to use the db Adapter.

I realy love `Zend_Db_Table`, the only problem is the amount of metadata send every requests, but you can handle this with some caching.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Does Zend_DB_Table implement caching?

Comment: Yes Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache); See docu for more info

Comment: Uhh. That's not really the caching he's asking about. The meta data cache is exactly that--`Zend_Db_Table` needs information about the table, and that's just a cache so it doesn't have to perform a `DESCRIBE TABLE` on every single request.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So the actual data isn't cached?

Comment: No, you have to configure zend_cache for it.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html